# Importing a txt semi-colon delimited file via php and into a new format

Tags: php, javascript, import

I might have bitten off more than I can chew with this one, but hopefully you guys can help. Here's the story.

I have a user generated .txt file that gets updated regularly through the day via a calendar module I have installed on my site. I need to be able to access SOME of that data to block out dates that are reserved in the calendar. First, here's the syntax of the calendar .txt file. To make it more readable, I'll put each segment of data on its own line:

```
2012-11-08;;1;;0,
2012-11-09;;1;;0,
2012-11-10;;1;;0,
2012-11-13;;2;;0,
2012-11-14;;2;;0,
2012-12-05;;1;;150,
2012-12-06;;1;;150
```

Here's where things get complicated though. I can easily import this using a little php script into my CMS. But I only need certain data from the above feed, and I need it organized in a slightly different format than it's currently being output in. I am using the jquery datepicker on another calendar to show the availability to guests, and I have a JS script that blocks out dates using this format.

```
var disabledDays = [
    "11-21-2012",
    "12-17-2012",
    "12-02-2012",
    "01-03-2013",
    "01-04-2013",
    "01-05-2013"
];
```

Any item in the .txt file that has a "2" or "0" after the date is a "Booked" or "Unavailable" date, respectively, and needs to be included in the JS feed above; i.e.; 2012-11-13;;2;;0,

The final number in the .txt file, which above was either a 0 or 150 can be discarded entirely, as that's the price and isn't relevant to the JS calendar. And the final thing is the date is in a slightly different order in the .txt file than what I need it to be in the .JS file (which I'll create using PHP).

I am sure all of the above is possible using PHP, but I'm running in circles trying to get this working. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have many ideas, but more importantly - what is the question?

Comment: Hey John, Kindly edit the question to add what exactly you want here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have trouble with the date format and accessing the data of the text file, you can always use the explode function to separate the element correctly and after that is a matter of iterating through the elements, something like:

```
$string = '2012-11-08;;1;;0,
2012-11-09;;1;;0,
2012-11-10;;1;;0,
2012-11-13;;2;;0,
2012-11-14;;2;;0,
2012-12-05;;1;;150,
2012-12-06;;1;;150';

$element = explode(",", $string);
$array = array();
foreach($element as $row){
    array_push($array, explode(";", $row));
}

foreach($array as $date){
    $newdate = new DateTime($date[0]);
    $newdate = $newdate->format('m-d-Y');
    echo $newdate;
    if($date[2] == 2)
        //Do your processing
       echo "Book";
```

}

There's probably a better solution and faster I'm just trying to point how you can do it with php.